# Trim Leading string and Zero in C#

Tags: c#

In `SQL Server` I am using this syntax to remove leading `string` and `Zero`:

```
SUBSTRING(@DELIVERYNO, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @DELIVERYNO), LEN(@DELIVERYNO))
```

with `@DELIVERYNO` is `ABC-000001`  or `CDE-000026`

After remove, `02` above string will be : `1`  or `26`

How to do it in `C#` code?

Comment: Use [TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Cannot apply in my case

Comment: C# has both regex and substring functions too. Just look them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a one liner:

```
var Result = DeliveryNo.Substring(4).TrimStart('0');
```

If you want to test it firts you can first remove the prefix, since it has fixed length, and then remove all trailing zeroes:

```
var DeliveryNo = "ABC-000001";

var WithoutPrefix = DeliveryNo.Substring(4);
Console.WriteLine(WithoutPrefix); // Displays 000001


var NoZeroes = WithoutPrefix.TrimStart('0');
Console.WriteLine(NoZeroes); // Displays 1
```

Some info:

- `.Substring(4)` will take a substring starting from position 4 to the end of your string, i.e. from the first digit to the last
- `.TrimStart('0')` will remove all zeroes to the left of your string

---

If you have a list you can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var DeliveryNumbers = new List<string>() {"VLD-002546","VIV-012345"};

var Result = DeliveryNumbers.Select(f=> f.Substring(4).TrimStart('0')).ToList();

Result.ForEach(f=> Console.WriteLine(f));
```

Or, if you want your result as a single string comma-separated:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", Result));
```

Here you have:

- `Select` will perform an action on all items of your `List`
- `f=> f.Substring(4).TrimStart('0')` simply means: if I call `f` any item of the `List` provided to `Select`, what I want to do with it is extract a substring and then remove all trailing zeroes
- `Result.ForEach(f=> Console.WriteLine(f));` is just a foreach loop, written as a one-liner, which I wrote to let you test the results

Comment: Yeah, could possibly also go for index of `-`. It depends on the actual pattern of all possible input, and the original question doesn't really specify that.

Comment: How to do with List <string> ?  "VLD-002546,VIV-012345"

Comment: @user3035133 You loop through it using a `for` loop. That's really the basics of _any_ programming...

Comment: I need to keep the return value after removing leading string and zero to pass this value to SQL store procedure. Return value should be "1,26" for the sample data: "ABC-000001,CDE-000026"

Comment: I edited my answer to deal with a List

Comment: @user3035133 Then the question you posted is incomplete. Edit it and add what code you have, and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @user3035133 I edited my answer to output the result as numbers separated by a comma, as you wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use regular expressions:

```
//System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex 
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString,@"[1-9]+\d*").Value;
```

This will return first match for your string.

Comment: What if the string is `ABC-000201`?

Comment: You are right. Let me correct answer.

Comment: You know, regex has `\d` as shorthand for "any digit". Though in your defense, OP's own regex has that wrong for including zeroes.

Comment: @Nyerguds, I know, but here we want to avoid zeros at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, indeed. OP's regex is only meant to find the start index.

Comment: But Regex not work with List <string> I want to remove the string from the List <string>  var val = string.Join(",", Regex.Match(frm1._DELIVERYNO, @"[1-9]+\d*").Value);   frm1._DELIVERYNO is List<string> ,Ex: VLD-000254, VID-000354

Comment: @user3035133 You never specified any such thing. In fact, you never posted any c# code _at all_. We're not psychic, and S.O. is not a code writing service. If you made some attempt, _put it in the question_, and tell us what your _real_ problem is.

Comment: @user3035133 Also, that just means you need to loop through it. Which is another very, very basic thing in c#. Please, at least look up _some_ basics of the language before trying to write a program in it.